Login doesn't work even though the credentials are correct in Laravel and mySQL
i'm having issues where i'm trying to make a login page while connecting it into my mySQL, i've tried most solutions and it's not working for me,what keeps happening is it keeps going into else in LoginController even though the credentials are correct, i assume i did something stupid but couldn't point it out, i need all the help i can get here
Login Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('home');
        }else{
            return view('loginKaryawan');
        }
    }

    public function actionlogin(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
        $karyawan = Auth::user();
        return redirect()->route('dashboardMO');
    } else {
        Session::flash('error', 'Username atau Password Salah. Username: ' . $data['username'] . ', Password: ' . $data['password']);
        return redirect('/');   
    }
}


    public function actionlogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}

KaryawanController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\karyawan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class karyawanController
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $karyawan = karyawan::all();

        if (count($karyawan) > 0) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Retrieve All Success',
                'data' => $karyawan
            ], 200);
        }

        return response([
            'message' => 'Empty',
            'data' => null
        ], 400);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $storeData = $request->all();

        $validate = Validator::make($storeData, [
            'nama_karyawan' => 'required',
            'no_telp' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'gaji_karyawan' => 'required',
            'bonus' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validate->fails()) {
            return response(['message' => $validate->errors()], 400);
        }

        $karyawan = karyawan::create($storeData);
        return response([
            'message' => 'Add karyawan Success',
            'data' => $karyawan
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $id_karyawan)
    {
        $karyawan = karyawan::find($id_karyawan);

        if (!is_null($karyawan)) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'karyawan found, it is ' . $karyawan->nama_karyawan,
                'data' => $karyawan
            ], 200);
        }

        return response([
            'message' => 'karyawan Not Found',
            'data' => null
        ], 404);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, string $id_karyawan)
    {
        $karyawan = karyawan::find($id_karyawan);
        if (is_null($karyawan)) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'karyawan Not Found',
                'data' => null
            ], 404);
        }

        $updateData = $request->all();
        $validate = Validator::make($updateData, [
            'nama_karyawan' => 'required',
            'no_telp' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'gaji_karyawan' => 'required',
            'bonus' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validate->fails()) {
            return response(['message' => $validate->errors()], 400);
        }

        $karyawan->nama_karyawan = $updateData['nama_karyawan'];
        $karyawan->no_telp = $updateData['no_telp'];
        $karyawan->username = $updateData['username'];
        $karyawan->password = $updateData['password'];
        $karyawan->gaji_karyawan = $updateData['gaji_karyawan'];
        $karyawan->bonus = $updateData['bonus'];

        if ($karyawan->save()) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Update karyawan Success ',
                'data' => $karyawan
            ], 200);
        }

        return response([
            'message' => 'Update karyawan Failed',
            'data' => null
        ], 400);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(string $id_karyawan)
    {
        $karyawan = karyawan::find($id_karyawan);

        if (is_null($karyawan)) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'karyawan Not Found',
                'data' => null
            ], 404);
        }

        if ($karyawan->delete()) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Delete karyawan Success ',
                'data' => $karyawan
            ], 200);
        }

        return response([
            'message' => 'Delete karyawan Failed ',
            'data' => null
        ], 400);
    }
}


 Web Routes
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('actionlogin', [LoginController::class, 'actionlogin'])->name('actionlogin');
Route::get('dashboardMO', [karyawanController::class,'index'])->name('dashboardMO')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('actionlogout', [LoginController::class, 'actionlogout'])->name('actionlogout')->middleware('auth');

Karyawan Models
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableTrait;

class karyawan extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, AuthenticatableTrait;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = "karyawan";
    protected $primaryKey = "id_karyawan";

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'nama_karyawan',
        'no_telp',
        'gaji_karyawan',
        'bonus',
    ];

    public function karyawan(){
        return $this->belongsTo(karyawan::class, 'id_role');
    }
}


loginKaryawan.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Login - Atma Kitchen</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <h2 class="text-center"><b>ATMA KITCHEN</b><br>Login Karyawan Atma Kitchen</h3>
            <hr>
            @if(session('error'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <b>Opps!</b> {{session('error')}}
            </div>
            @endif
            <form action="{{ route('actionlogin') }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
                <hr>
                <p class="text-center">Lupa Password? <a href="#">Recover</a> </p>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


So you've dumped your entire project here, but what debugging have you done?

i have checked if the login went through and it did

Do you have any errors? are you reaching Auth::attempt($data) and it is succeeding or failing? You need to add more information

sorry, this is the first time i ask here, it doesn't have any error, it reached but immediately went to else

The problem is with the way you're redirecting the user to login route after the registration. You're falsely assuming that the $request data will be accompanied with the redirect.
Let's assume this scenario: A request gets dispatched to the postRegister method with name, email and password fields. The controller creates the user and saves it into the database. Then it redirects the user, who is not yet authenticated, to the login route. The postLogin method gets triggered, but this time with no request data. As a result, Auth::attempt($credentials) fails and you get that nasty Failure on screen.
If you add a dd($credentials) right after you create the array, you'll see that it has no values:
public function actionlogin(Request $request)
 {
    $data = [
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ];

    // Dump data
    dd($data);

    if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
        $karyawan = Auth::user();
        return redirect()->route('dashboardMO');
    }
    
    return 'Failure';
}

It will return something like this:
array:2 [
  "username" => null
  "password" => null
]

You cannot redirect with custom request data (unless with querystring which is part of the URL), not matter what. It's not how HTTP works. Request data aside, you can't even redirect with custom headers.
Now that you know what's the root of your problem, let's see what are the options to fix it.

Redirect with flashed data
In case you want to preserve this structure, you need to flash the request data of postRegister() into the session (which is persistent between requests) and then retrieve it in the postLogin() method using Session facade, session() helper or the actual Illuminate\Session\SessionManager class.

Here's what I mean:
(I slightly modified your code; dropped extra variables, made it a lil bit cleaner, etc.)
public function actionregister(Request $request)
{
    // Retrieve all request data including username, email & password.
    // I assume that the data IS validated.
    $input = $request->all();

    // Hash the password
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

    // Create the user
    User::create($input);

    // Redirect
    return redirect()
        // To the route named `login`
        ->route('login')

        // And flash the request data into the session,
        // if you flash the `$input` into the session, you'll
        // get a "Failure" message again. That's because the 
        // password in the $input array is already hashed and 
        // the attempt() method requires user's password, not 
        // the hashed copy of it. 
        //
        ->with($request->only('username', 'password'));
}

public function actionlogin(Request $request)
{
    // Create the array using the values from the session
    $data = [
        'username' => session('username'),
        'password' => session('password'),
    ];

    // Attempt to login the user
    if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
        $karyawan = Auth::user();
        return redirect()->route('dashboardMO');
    }

    return 'Failure';
}

I strongly recommend you against using this approach. This way the implementation of actionlogin() method which is supposed to be responsible to login users gets coupled with session data which is not good. This way, you're not able to use postLogin independently from the postRegister.

Login the user right after the registration
This is a slightly better solution; If you decided that you need to log in the user right after the registration, why not just doing that?

Note that Laravel's own authentication controller does it automatically.
By the way, here's what I mean:
(Ideally this should be broken down into multiple methods, just like Laravel's own authentication controller. But it's just an example to get you started.)
public function actionregister(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

    User::create($input);

    // event(UserWasCreated::class);

    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('username', 'password'))) {
        return redirect()
            ->route('dashboard')
            ->with('Welcome! Your account has been successfully created!');
    }

    // Redirect
    return redirect()
        // To the previous page (probably the one generated by a getRegister method)
        ->back()
        // And with the input data (so that the form will get populated again)
        ->withInput();
}

But still, it's far from perfect! There are many other ways to tackle this. One could be using events, throwing exceptions on failure and redirecting using custom exceptions. But I'm not gonna explore them as there's already a solution perfectly designed for this.
If you want to write your own authentication controller, that's fine. You'll learn a lot along the way. But I strongly suggest reading Laravel's own authentication code, especially RegistersUsers and AuthenticatesUsers traits in order to learn from it.enter code here
And one more note; you don't need that Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable trait in your User model as it's already extending Authenticatable which use that trait.

thank you for the current answer, but in this case it's like an admin login, so there's no register, and when i dumped the data it shows up correctly and the same as the data in the mysql database, i'm sorry for broken english and such i'm still learning
